# apt-get upgrade is producing a GUI interaction and is prohibiting an interaction-free upgrade

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, upgrade

So I am writing a script that changes various aspects of an Ubuntu 16.04.4 machine and one of the tasks is upgrading all packages. To do this I use`apt-get -y upgrade`. (`-y` for auto yes on dialogue and provide automation) This works fine and is automated for nearly all packages but once every so often I will get the interaction pane depicted below.

[image]

I'm assuming there is no easy way to handle and answer these dialogues in a uniform way across all packages but is there a way to disable such an interaction and provide a truly automated, interaction-free upgrade?

Comment: I do get that but I am deploying this script under the precondition that no user is ever going to be interacting with the output so that `-y` flag is necessary frankly what I desire ~90% of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can do a couple of things for avoiding this. Setting the
>   `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` variable to `noninteractive` and using `-y` flag.
>   For example:
>
> ```
> export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
> apt-get -yq install [packagename]
> ```
>
> If you need to install it via sudo, use:
>
> ```
> sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -yq install [packagename]
> ```

<sup>([source](https://serverfault.com/a/227194))</sup>

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! There's another and more important reason to include the relevant parts of linked resources than convenience in line: the linked resource may change or vanish in a way that invalidates the answer. Link-only answers are discouraged and usually deleted in review for that reason on Stack Exchange.